# NullReferenceException while adding to dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm using `instrument2Orders` dictionary. I'm adding to it using `instrument` as a key and `ordersOfGlass` as value. All my instances or not `null` what proves output below, but I still receive `System.NullReferenceException` how is that possible?

```
private Dictionary<Instrument, List<Order>> instrument2Orders = new Dictionary<Instrument, List<Order>>();

.........
        public void InitialRegisterOrder(Order order)
            .....
        if (instrument2Orders.ContainsKey(instrument))
        {
            ordersOfGlass = instrument2Orders[instrument];
        }
        else
        {
            ordersOfGlass = new List<Order>();
            try
            {
                instrument2Orders.Add(instrument, ordersOfGlass);
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
                Console.WriteLine("XYZ! instrument = " + instrument + " ordersOfGlass = " + ordersOfGlass + " instrument2Orders = " + instrument2Orders);
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
System.NullReferenceException: ‘бл«Є  ­  ®ЎкҐЄв ­Ґ гЄ §лў Ґв ­  нЄ§Ґ¬Ї«па ®ЎкҐЄв .
   ў System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   ў MBClient.Market.InitialRegisterOrder(Order order) ў C:\Oleg\projects\MBClient\MBClient\Market.cs:бва®Є  233

XYZ! instrument = ClassCode: EQNL Ticker: GAZP. ordersOfGlass = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Commons.Order] instrument2Orders = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[Commons.Instrument,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Commons.Order]]
```

Instrument class:

```
class Instrument
{
    //public Instrument(int id, string classCode, string ticker)
    //{
    //    this.Ticker = ticker;
    //    this.ClassCode = classCode;
    //}

    public string ClassCode { get; set; }
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ClassCode: " + ClassCode + " Ticker: " + Ticker + '.';
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Instrument instrument = obj as Instrument;
        if (instrument == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (ClassCode.Equals(instrument.ClassCode)) && (Ticker.Equals(instrument.Ticker));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + ClassCode.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + Ticker.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of the above code raises the exception?

Comment: Are there multiple threads involved in your case which are accessing the Dictionary instance

Comment: Can you translate "‘бл«Є  ­  ®ЎкҐЄв ­Ґ гЄ §лў Ґв ­  нЄ§Ґ¬Ї«па ®ЎкҐЄв" to English? Google Translate struggled to come up with anything helpful.

Comment: @joocer "Reference to the object doesn't point to the instance of the object"

Comment: @Steve line that surrounded with `try`

Comment: @V4Vendetta you are probably right. I likely access Dictionary from different threads.

Comment: @V4Vendetta should I make `ContainsKey` call thread-safe? for example may I call `ContainsKey` from one thread while calling `Add` from another thread?

Comment: @V4Vendetta I fixed threading problem and now it seems everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

First instinct: instrument is null.

Where does this variable come from? It's not a parameter, is it a field?

Comment: No, null isn't a valid key for a Dictionary<K,V>; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx - however, Dictionary.Add() will throw ArgumentNullException if it is null, and the OP's exception is NullReferenceException

Comment: @MatthewWatson You are absolutely correct, i think it may be coz of some  threading issue, maybe some other thread is modifying it

Answer (score 0):

Does your Instrument class override GetHashCode() by any chance?

If it does and if it dereferences a null ref, you'll get something like that error (although the stack trace seems to indicate something different is going on...)

Anyway, this program will give you a NullReferenceException when you do dict.Add() even though the key and value are both non-null:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            var dict = new Dictionary<Test, Test>();
            dict.Add(test, test);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: added `Instrument` class to the topic

Comment: Ok, can you provide a complete compilable example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: i made `instrument2Orders` access thread-safe and this fixed the problem